# Set centralised user home folders in LDAP Ubuntu

Tags: nfs, ldap

I have created couple of users on my ldap, and setup a couple of ubuntu ldap client machines, where users can login with their accounts. The problem is that if a user logins into two machines with his account, then for example creates files or folders in his home folder for example on the desktop in one of the two machines, he can't see the folder on the other machine. I wonder how to make the home folders of my users centralised so that updates are synched straight away across the machines? So that when a user logins in with his account from any machine he can see that it's the same and that his files and folders are there. Any advice please?

Comment: how about a mounted Network Storage that is mounted at /home/{user} which is rolled out with LDAP or Installation (don't know if it's even possible to create files with LDAP)

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that the directory of LDAP users is **/home/ldap**:

On the server:
1-Create the **/home/ldap** folder
2-Share it with NFS (edit **/etc/exports** and add something like this):

```
/home/ldap   *(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,no_wdelay,sync)
```

3-Restart or reload NFS service

In the clients:
1-Create the **/home/ldap** folder
2-Get it mounted automatically (edit **/etc/fstab** and add something like this):

```
192.168.1.10:/home/ldap   /home/ldap   nfs    _netdev,auto,hard,intr  0  4
```